# Firebase observer not working, why won't it keep a watch on the value change?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

I am trying to set a Firebase observer by calling the following:

```
ref.child(id).child("isLocked").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    print("isLocked = ", snapshot.value!)

})
```

When the view loads it works perfectly. It prints out the correct value.

When I go change the value either in Firebase itself or on a separate device the isLocked is never printed again. When it should be since I have an observer on the path. What gives?

The end goal here is to have a UIButton available based on if the `lock` value is true of false.

The view is loaded with the `button.isHidden = true`.

**UPDATE**

I found the source of my issue with observer not "Working"

It would seem that there is a timing issue.

In the previous view controller (which segues into the new view controller) I am calling `ref.child(pID).child("isLocked").removeAllObservers()` in the 'viewDidDisappear' function

And in the new view controller I am 'trying' to setup the same path observer 'ref.child(id).child("isLocked").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in'

which I guess the `removeAllObservers()` trumps the setup of the new observer!? How do I get over this!?

Comment: Can you include the minimal code that shows how you change the database on the other device?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm going directly in Firebase and changing the lock value from true to false and vise versa and nothing happens.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I also added more detail to what I am trying to achieve with the `lock` value switching to true or false

Comment: That's very uncommon. Are you sure you're changing the `isLocked` under the correct ID? Also note, since you said "or on a separate device" I assumed you could also make the change in code, which makes it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes... if I put the observer on `.childChanged' it does work!? but again its only on change.... I have no clue why it wont take on .value!?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i updated the question, it seems like its a timing issue with removing the previous VC observer and trying to create the new observer in the new VC. How can I fix that, if you know!?

Comment: Changing the type of listener won't make a difference. The `value` event fires when the data at or under the reference or query changes. I'm not sure what the race condition is. It's hard to give a specific answer without seeing the minimal code that reproduces it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen see my response and you can try it yourself. Using the `ref.child(pID).child("isLocked").removeAllObservers() in the viewDidDisappear` in the first view controller and calling the same 'path' `ref.child(pID).child("isLocked")` in the view controller segued to will not allow the observer to set. This may be a Firebase issue.

Comment: You might want to check when `viewDidDisappear` and the new view controller run. I expect you'll find that the `viewDidDisappear` fires last (since the new view needs to show before the old one can disappear), and thus your call to `removeAllObservers` happens after you attach the listener in the new view.

Comment: Here's the issue; the code we need to see is not included in your question and the code included in your question is somewhat unrelated to the question. *When the view loads it works perfectly. It prints out the correct value.* which may be because it's being called during the loading process. However, if your view goes out of scope, so does that code so it would not be called if you change the value within the Firebase console. However, that's just a guess. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of my issue with observer not "Working"

It would seem that there is a timing issue.

In the previous view controller (which segues into the new view controller) I am calling `ref.child(pID).child("isLocked").removeAllObservers()` in the `viewDidDisappear` function

And in the new view controller I am 'trying' to setup the same 'path observer' `ref.child(id).child("isLocked").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in`.

Which I guess the `removeAllObservers()` trumps the setup of the new observer!?

To remedy this you need to setup specific handles per observer! Make sure to use unique var names and no reuse and then call the following instead of `removeAllObservers()`:

```
ref.child(id).child("isLocked").removeObserver(withHandle: confirmVCRefHandle!)
```

the above handle name `confirmVCRefHandle` is unique and the timing issue is overcome!

Comment: "I guess the removeAllObservers() trumps the setup of the new observer!?" Nope, that seems very unlikely. The two calls are unrelated, and Firebase has no knowledge of the views in your app. More likely is that your` removeAllObservers()` call happens after you've registered the observer in the new view, hence that observer is immediately removed.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am in agreement, thus why I said its a 'timing' issue. But as I wrote in my 'response' the need to ensure you use unique handles is require since, and you also stated, the viewDidDisappear and the new view controller run. I expect you'll find that the viewDidDisappear fires last (since the new view needs to show before the old one can disappear), and thus the call to removeAllObservers happens after attaching the listener in the new view.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ref.child(id).observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in

    if snapshot.key == "isLocked" {
        if let value = snapshot.value as? Bool {
            print(value)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Observing on `.childchanged` won't start the listener until after the value changes as least once. So it does not work for my use case.

Comment: Also I changed the value in Firebase directly and the observer did not listen for the change.

Comment: Yeah. In my project I use both .childChanged and .childAdded. And .childRemoved too.
I believe only .childAdded loads all values when it starts and later adds only added then items.

Comment: .value will reduce your code and not require .childAdded, .childChanged and in the instance there is .childRemoved